# JUnit : my XML file location in @ContextConfiguration isn't found

Tags: spring, junit

This is my JUnit class :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "WEB-INF/spring-test-config.xml"})    
public class TestXXXX extends TestBase
{ ...
```

When I launch this test class with JUnit runner (from Eclipse), it's failed, because the file `spring-test-config.xml` is not found.

My project architecture is :

- `/src/main/com/xxx/` : my source code
- `/src/main/WEB-INF/` : my config files; under this folder there is `spring-test-config.xml` : this file **is not the final xml** because it contains some tokens which replace by a Ant target. And the final result of this file is place in `WebContent` (deploy directory in fact) - see above.
- `/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/com/xxx/` : my *binary* code
- `/WebContent/WEB-INF/spring-test-config.xml`

So, how can i do to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Skaffman, my classpath are : /src/main/ folder. All my spring files are generated with my ant target (for replace some tokens) and put in WebContent/WEB-INF/

Answer (score 5):

Can you show all your project structure, and where is your test class placed too.

Configure directories in classpath from eclipse.

After that you can define your spring-context application file in `src/resources/test` directory and load it with `@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/spring-test-config.xml"})`.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this problem before - you need to add the WEB-INF folder to your build path.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to check your ant configuration.

I had the same problem (using Maven) and tried Ricardo's and Katie's ideas no to avail, then I put a test config file into /src/test/resources (note the subtle difference) and only then did '@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/spring-test-config.xml"})' work.  In conclusion, you probably want to go with Ricardo's idea and then check your build process.